# Azure DevOps update multiple databases in a single release deployment

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

**Can Azure DevOps update multiple databases in a single release deployment?**

I have a repository in MS DevOps with Pipelines that builds and a release to deploy in Azure Web App. This release also runs the Entity Framework migration in Azure SQL Database. Everything is perfect.

But I can't deploy the application (EF's migration) to multiple databases with the same schema (tables, views, etc.) In the Azure Web App it's possible only to configure 1 connection string.

I don't want to have multiples Web Apps, just 1 Web App with multiple databases.

This is a multi-tenant application. So in run-time, depending on the user, dynamically switch the connection string to point to the desired database. It's like having different environments of the same app.

Comment: It sounds like [Elastic Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/elastic-jobs-overview) might be a solution, but I have no experience with it, just research.

Comment: Hmm, I don't quite understand the issue. You can have different EF DbContexts in an app which use different databases. Where are you limited to one database?

Comment: @juunas no, I have only one database. In runtime, depending to the user, dynamically selects the connection string to point to the correct database.
It's like having different environments of the same app.

Comment: Ahh, so a kind of multi-tenant app?

Comment: You'd probably need to put an nginx front end or similar in front of your application